# Find average from text file

Tags: java, arrays, text

I am trying to find the average of numbers on the same line in a text file, for every line.
For example, if this is the text file:

```
8.7 6.5 0.1 3.2 5.7 9.9 8.3 6.5 6.5 1.5
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

I want to print something like:

```
For Competitor #1, the average is 5.8625
For Competitor #2, the average is 0.0000
For Competitor #3, the average is 1.0000
```

This is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class BaseClass
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
    fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Name\\DataGym.in.txt"));
    int maxIndx = -1;
    String text[] = new String[1000];

    while (sf.hasNext()) {
        maxIndx++;
        text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine();
    }
    sf.close();
    int contestant = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(text[j]);
        double scoreAverage = 0;
        double a = 0;
        double array[] = new double[1000];
        contestant++;
        if (j <= 10) {
            a += sc.nextDouble();
            array[j] += a;
        } else {
            Arrays.sort(array);
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10) {
                scoreAverage += array[i];
                i++;
            }
        }

            String s = fmt.format(scoreAverage);
            double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
         System.out.println("For Competitor #" + contestant + ", the average is " + d);
    }
    }
}
```

It prints

```
For the Competitor #1, the average is 0.0
For the Competitor #2, the average is 0.0
For the Competitor #3, the average is 0.0
```

Comment: You need to debug your code or post your analysis, this is too broad a question to answer (and maybe do your homework?)

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating the problem here. Following snippet is enough to make you achieve what you are trying to achieve here.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Name\\DataGym.in.txt"));
    int counter = 0;
    String line = null;
    while(in.hasNext()) {
        line = in.nextLine();
        double sum = 0;
        String[] splits = line.split(" ");
        for(String s : splits) {
            sum += Double.parseDouble(s);
        }
        System.out.println("For Competitor #" + (++counter) 
                           + ", the average is " + (sum/splits.length));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
For Competitor #1, the average is 5.69
For Competitor #2, the average is 0.0
For Competitor #3, the average is 1.0
```